# When i ionic app build at that time build is successful but when i emulate with android at that time give following error

Tags: cordova, ionic2

When i ionic app build at that time build is successful but when i emulate with android at that time give following error

```
D:/Demo-Projects/tabsapp/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk: 
1 file pushed. 1.2 MB/s (4213012 bytes in 3.437s)

        pkg: /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk enter code here

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

rm failed for -f, Read-only file system

**[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova emulate android (exit code 1).**
```

advance thanks a lot please help me i am stuck here.

Comment: I am not used android studio i have just use AVD emulator. app is not emulate in AVD emulator i think problem is this error.

Comment: maybe you have an older app already installed in the emulator with difference in package structure? try uninstalling the app from your emulator and then running your command

Comment: No dear not any older app already installed in AVD emulator

Comment: try `ionic cordova emulate android --verbose`

Comment: Dear Still gives error build is successful but error is given below


BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 8.257 secs
Built the following apk(s):
        D:/Demo-Projects/tabsapp/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Designer9\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151
Error: Device communication timed out. Try unplugging & replugging the device.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova emulate android (exit code 1).

[DEBUG] registerShutdownFunction process.exit/normal shutdown

Comment: hmm.. device timeout seems like a different issue from the question...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159111/discussion-between-aman-gojariya-and-suraj-rao).

Comment: Okay dear let start in the chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem Solved using the declaration of Sdk Version in AndroidManifest.xml file and also to be noted that in SDK install api in SDK tool which version of declare in **android:minSdkVersion**.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The error **INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK** means that your app is built with a minimum version of android that is higher than the version of android of your emulator.

The error happens when the app is deployed to the device/emulator, after the apk is built.

To solve the issue, either use an emulator running a newer version of android or change the minimum sdk version of the app.

You can configure the minimum sdk version in config.xml:

```
...
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
</platform>
...
```

Here we set the minSDK to 16, you have to adjust depending on the minimum version you want to cover.

If you already have a `platform name="android"` section in your config.xml just add the `preference` line, if not, add the section.